# Issue with Win32com and Excel when user is editing a cell while trying to launch the program

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I'm trying to automate task on Excel with python. For this projetc it is imperative that excel is able to stay open on the same file that the program is editing. in the current state, it is working, unless the user is editing a cell on the excel file. Is there any way to prevent this by any mean ?

Here the code in question, with the error message that it gives when a user is editing a cell
(the VBA version is for the finished product that will be called by a button on the execl file, with the help of a tiny bit of VBA)

```
import win32com.client as win32
import sys
import tkinter


# Initialize Excel
excel = win32.Dispatch("Excel.Application")

# Define the path of the Excel file to modify

# VBA version
#excel_file_path = sys.argv[1]

# Python dev version
excel_file_path = "D:\PROJET QUADRO\Refonte_Planning_QUADRO - Copy.xlsx"


# Open the WorkBook
try:
    
    global workbook, ws
    workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(excel_file_path)
    ws = workbook.ActiveSheet
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error opening Excel file: {str(e)}")
    exit()
    
# Manipulation function
def write_cell(cell, value):
    """Write the given value to the given cell"""
    ws.Cells(cell).Value = value
    
def read_cell(cell):
    """Read the value of the given cell and return it"""
    return ws.Range(cell).Value

print(read_cell("A45"))
```

Error opening Excel file: Excel.Application.Workbooks

Process ended with exit code 0.

I asked chat gpt and he told me to add this line

```
excel.Application.Wait(1000)
```

After multiple attemps and revision, it never worked
Other attempts :

```
excel.Wait(-1)
excel.ActiveWorkbook.Wait(-1)
```

I tried to do a While True loop that check every so often with a try and except, but the program is not able to open the workbook, thus preventing me to check if a cell is beign edited
furthemore, i need the programm to launch no matter what, and if there is a probleme to warn the user, and no crash